# Can we have a downward power stage sequence in stratified Z?

Tags: axioms, alternative-set-theories

See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390391/is-existence-of-this-set-consistent-with-zermelo-set-theory-minus-choice) question on Mathoverflow.

Can we have this with *stratified* Zermelo. Where the latter is Zermelo set theory but with separation restricted to [stratified formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Axioms_and_stratification) only. To present the question in full, I'll re-iterate it here:

Define a *pre-ordinal* as a transitive set of transitive sets.

Is it consistent with ***Stratified*** [Zermelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory#The_axioms_of_Zermelo_set_theory) set theory (without choice) to have a nonempty set $S$ such that: for every element $s \in S$ there exists a pre-ordinal $\beta$ and a set $Y$ such that $s=\langle \beta, Y \rangle $, and there exists an element $r \in S$ such that: $r= \langle \alpha, X \rangle$, where $\beta=\alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$ and $Y = \cal P$$(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: When you say "stratified", do you mean in the New Foundations sense?

Comment: @Yes! of course. I've edited it to make that clear. Thanks!